# Unable to use Rails Composer on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, rvm, twitter-bootstrap-rails

[Rails Composer](http://railsapps.github.com/rails-composer/) is a tool for auto-generating template rails applications. Maybe I'm stupid but I can't get it up and running on Windows.

I managed to create an app using

```
rails new myapp -m https://raw.github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/master/composer.rb
```

But I have no idea how to configure the options so I can use MongoDB + Twiter Bootstrap (SASS) + OpenAuth.

Using the rvm part of the tutorial isn't really an option since I'm on windows.

By the way, does anyone have an automated workflow of creating apps with rails composer and deploying them to Heroku?

Comment: Hi, did you resolve that?

Comment: It was so long ago that I don't recall. I think we just ditched windows and went for Ubuntu VM for the dev box. @IamnotBatman

Comment: lol, cool solution indeed. @JohnnyM